# VBA Modules file storage location

Tags: vba

The title of my question might be a bit ambiguous so let me elaborate:

I was curious as to where these are stored on the computer, if at all? I find it a bit difficult to believe that it is solely stored within the application itself. I was digging around in folders such as

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office"
```

To see if maybe there was a .dll that might stick out, but I only see a couple of files named vbaoff8.cnt & vbagrp8.cnt

I tired searching for an answer to this, but I am guessing I am not wording it correctly to yield the correct results.

Anybody happen to know anything about this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you are searching for the binaries of the VBEditor itself?
If yes then look for files named `VBE7.DLL` and `VBEUI.DLL`.
I have them at this location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1`. You could just search for `Microsoft Shared\VBA`

Comment: @CS IDK but its a good start thanks